# Why windows task bar custom task list doesn`t work without pin on windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qml, taskbar

The minimal working example with [QML JumpList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwinextras-jumplist.html) (same behaviour if using [QWinJumpList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwinjumplist.html) in c++).

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWinExtras 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    JumpList {
        JumpListCategory {
            visible: true
            title: "Test"

            JumpListLink {
                title: "Test Link"
                executablePath: "http://google.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After launch appliction you may press right mouse button on the application in windows task bar and look at something like:

[image: custom menu in application task bar]

If press to `Test Link` menu item the default browser with `http://google.com` url should be opened because of under the hood it uses shell execute. This work well in windows 7, 8, 8.1.

In windows 10 this doesn`t work while you do not pin application to task bar by hands. After this done the link is working.

Why this so and how it can be fixed?

**UPDATE 1**: This strange behaviour was tested with Qt 5.5, 5.5.1, 5.6 and master branch on Windows 10 - dev, first released home version, final home, pro. And results is same - not working. Also, for example, chrome uses custom list (the `site` section) and it works well without pinning.

**UPDATE 2**: Here is my qt bug [QTBUG-49486](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49486) about this and related to it [QTBUG-48751](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48751). But the problem is right now the Qt devs do not know how to fix this problem too.

Comment: It seems to be the bug of the earlier releases of Windows 10. http://www.neowin.net/news/windows-10-10041-heres-how-to-enable-jump-lists-in-the-start-menu

Comment: Today i`l check it with our dev stand on earlier and final builds of windows 10. But still interesting why skype or chrome jump list work fine without pinning.

Comment: The same results on earlier (dev, first released home version) and final (home, pro) builds of windows 10 :(

Comment: It seems to that Qt 5.6 will be a solution:

http://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6
Desktop platforms
Windows 10 fully supported (classic and WinRT app)

Comment: Just test it with Qt 5.6 from they master branch. Same behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was fixed in windows 10 major update from 12.11.2015

Comment: Tnx for answer. Yes, in this major update this behaviour was fixed. But how about any workaround about this issue? Why chrome or skype works well without this patch?

Comment: I mean, why and how chrome/skype and other software works without this windows patch?